# Why does WAP Web Forms project fail to compile with no code changes?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, webforms, option-strict

In Visual Studio 2013, I created a new project via File > New Project > Installed.Templates.Visual Basic.Web.ASP.NET Web Application, and then selected the Web Forms suboption.

Without doing anything at all to the code - no additions, no modifications - I mashed F5 to make sure it ran a generic page. Instead, I got two build errors, both of the same type, namely, "*Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean' to 'String'*."

2-clicking the first one takes me to this line in Manage.aspx.vb:

```
HasPhoneNumber = String.IsNullOrEmpty(manager.GetPhoneNumber(User.Identity.GetUserId()))
```

The second error goes to this line in the same file:

```
TwoFactorEnabled = manager.GetTwoFactorEnabled(User.Identity.GetUserId())
```

Something is rotten in either Redlands or Monterey for a template project to not build correctly. What is going on here?

### UPDATE

Commenting out all the code in the Page_Load() method gets past the build problem, but still starts me off on a login page, which I don't want or need.

Comment: Not enough to go on...we dont know what those methods return or how those vars are declared.  Seems unlikely VS would be wrong though.  If the project was developed with Option Strict Off (seems likely from previously shown code), then you are paying the piper now with it on.

Comment: I changed nothing; Option Strict Off is not a global setting for all projects, is it? And besides, Option explicit and Option strict are both "On"

Comment: Option Strict is not off: the error message says so: `Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'Boolean' to 'String'.`

Comment: Right - it's ON, and you implied that having it Off would be a problem. Are you now saying having it On is a problem?

Comment: I have never, ever implied `Option Strict On` is a problem.  Being on now, it could be *revealing* issues if the project was built with it Off.

Comment: So Microsoft may have built the project template with it off, and not tested the behavior with it On (which seems to be the default setting, since I changed nothing)?

Comment: How are those vars (HasPhoneNumber, TwoFactorEnabled ) declared? They are named as if Boolean, and the code seems otherwise correct, but the error message indicates they are string

Comment: I don't know - I commented them out; I was just wondering why an OOTB project template would not compile. Seems bizarre and/or "unprofessional" to me.